# Shell script to count the number of uppercase and lowercase characers in a string input

Tags: shell-script, scripting

Suggest a shell script to find the number of uppercase and lowercase alphabets in a string using ASCII values.

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -Mopen=locale -e '
  $_="@ARGV";
  printf "upper: %d\nlower: %d\n", y/A-Z//, y/a-z//' -- "$myvar"
```

Would print the number of occurrences of ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ and abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz characters in the content of `$myvar`.

With `zsh`:

```
printf 'upper: %d\nlower: %d\n' ${#myvar//[^A-Z]} ${#myvar//[^a-z]}
```

With `ksh` or `bash`:

```
upper=ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
lower=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
u=${myvar//[^$upper]} l=${myvar//[^$lower]}
printf 'upper: %d\nlower: %d\n' "${#u}" "${#l}"
```

POSIXly:

```
upper=ABCDEFGHIJKMLNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
lower=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
u=$(printf %s "$myvar" | tr -cd "$upper" | wc -m)
l=$(printf %s "$myvar" | tr -cd "$lower" | wc -m)
printf 'upper: %d\nlower: %d\n' "$u" "$l"
```

Though beware that a few `tr` implementations like GNU `tr` are not compliant and could count parts of characters that happen to have the same encoding as ASCII letters. For instance in a `zh_HK.big5hkscs` locale on a GNU system:

```
$ LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs luit
$ printf Э | tr -cd ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | wc -c
1
```

As there, the encoding of `Э` happens to contain the encoding of `R`:

```
$ printf Э | hd
00000000  c8 52                                             |.R|
00000002
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of characters, you can use **[grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)** and a simple regex;  together with **[tr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr)** and **[wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)**

```
myVar="Valdeir Psr"
echo -n $myVar | grep -o [A-Z] | tr -d "\n" | wc -m
```

**What each command does:**

> `echo -n`   -->   Print the value of the variable
>
> `grep -o [A-Z]`   -->   Filters the uppercase letters
>
> `tr -d "\n"`   -->   Removes line break
>
> `wc -m`   -->   Print the character counts

To count the lowercase characters, simply replace `[A-Z]` with `[a-z]`

Comment: Except in `fish` (but `fish` variable assignment syntax is not like that), `[A-Z]` is a glob, so should be quoted. You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data. In most shells, `$myVar` would need to be quoted. Note that `grep -o` is a GNU extension, `echo -n` is not portable. `grep -o '[A-Z]'` in most locales matches on more than ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
s="Kyiv is the city of Archistratigus Michael ..."
awk 'BEGIN{ FPAT="[a-zA-Z]"; l=u=0 }
     {
         for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) ($i~/[a-z]/)? l++ : u++; 
         printf "upper: %d, lower: %d\n", l, u 
     }' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
upper: 33, lower: 3
```

---

- `FPAT="[a-zA-Z]"` - pattern defining field value (considers only uppercase and lowercase letters)

Answer (score 0):

To count the lower case characters in the string:

```
for i in {a..z}; do
  echo "Praven" | awk -v i="$i" '$1~i {print i}';
done | wc -l
```

Output

```
5
```

To find upper case characters instead, replace `a..z` with `A..Z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '{
    print "Uppercase", patsplit($0, a, /[A-Z]/)
    print "Lowercase", patsplit($0, a, /[a-z]/)
}' RS="\0" input.txt
```

Information about the `RS="\0"` construction - [Record Splitting with gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html).

**Input**

```
oNe TWo thrEE
```

**Output**

```
Uppercase 5
Lowercase 6
```